# Looking for new network endpoint for monitoring

Tags: monitoring, ping

Good afternoon, all!

I'm looking for a new static, highly reliable endpoint to ping as a network connectivity monitor. We had been using Google's DNS server address, but we just had trouble with it today.

Has anyone successfully used a different endpoint to ping? This would have to have excessive uptime and reliability - basically an endpoint that, if you can't ping it, the entire Internet is down.

Thanks for looking!

Gregg

Comment: If your standard is switching after a single incident, I'm not sure anyone's going to have significantly better uptime than Google's DNS. Are you looking to check multiple different endpoints for a better look?

Comment: No one IP address is going to be completely flawless.  Ping several, preferably on different networks if possible.

Comment: Are you really trying to determine if "the entire Internet is down"? This never happens, of course. First you need to more carefully define what it is you want to know.

Answer (score 4):

I think the cleaner way to monitor a site is to use an external source that monitors *you*. Unless you are using something that probes from your network to the outside to determine line status. If you have an option to use multiple endpoints, try 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4, 4.2.2.2 and maybe a [root DNS server address](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/servers). Better yet if you can do more than ping by establishing a TCP connection.

This is a common approach for the load/link balancers by [Elfiq](http://www.elfiq.com).

See: https://serverfault.com/a/820253/13325

Answer (score 0):

You need to ping multiple endpoints to confirm. If one host is available, your internet is available.